# Nothing works on the desktop screen after I tried to use the 3D cube settings

Tags: unity, command-line, taskbar

I am pretty new to 11.10. I was trying out some settings to operate the desktop in 3d cube mode that's when the unity bar, side bar disappeared. I have tried quite a few things to get it up and running but now even my terminal does not work with the shortcuts on the desktop.

Can someone please help me with what I need to do to resolve this conflict? Where do I begin?

Comment: Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), enter `compiz --replace` and press ENTER. Now restart your computer. It works?